# Issue with ember.js when querying for multiple records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have no issues using `store.findRecord()` and `store.findAll()` but when I try and use `store.query()` it always returns everything in the model, not a subset like I'm expecting.

For example, I have 100 records in my person model and when I use the example on the ember.js website in my route:

```
model: function() {
    this.get('store').query('person', {
      filter: {
        name: 'Peter'
      }
    }).then(function(peters) {
      return peters
    });
}
```

All 100 records are returned to my template instead of only those with the name 'Peter'.

Comment: I think you also want a return at the very start. Other than that, the model hook would look correct, and almost exactly like the docs example.

Comment: In which case, your issue could potentially be either whether the hook is actually called, or your how your GET requests are being handled.

Answer (score 0):

Your model hook should return.

```
model() {
        return this.get('store').query('person', {
          filter: {
            name: 'Peter'
          }
        }).then(function(peters) {
          return peters
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thats important..update ur question i will remove my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
model() {
  return this.store
    .findAll('person')
    .then(people =>
      people.filter(person => person.get('name').indexOf('Peter') >= 0)
    )
}
```

I don't think you can filter like that (I could be wrong). When you pass parameters to the `.query()` method, you're sending them server side, and rely on your API to filter and send back the correct data.

If you can't control that, you can just filter the records on client side. However, it would be fast to filter on the server side.

Comment: you can't call `query` without a query. Use `findAll` then instead!

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to ember. If you call `store.query` or `store.queryRecord` ember-data will sent the query to the server and expects the server to perform the required filter logic.

You should inform yourself about the difference between server and client side filtering. The difference is crucial!

Comment: Thank you.  You have me looking in the right direction now.  I wanted to filter server side and am using a Firebase backend.  I'm going to the look into the EmberFire documentation.